# How Gradle generates common tasks in multiproject/composite builds?

Tags: gradle, gradle-task

Let me illustrate the question with an example.

I have a project `my-commons`, which houses a lot of shared libraries used in my other projects, as well as common gradle plugins. The structure looks something like this:

```
my-commons
├─my-library-a
│ ├─...
│ └─build.gradle.kts
├─my-library-b
│ ├─...
│ └─build.gradle.kts
├─my-plugins
│ ├─...
│ └─build.gradle.kts
└─settings.gradle.kts
```

The root `settings.gradle.kts` file looks like this:

```kotlin
rootProject.name = "my-commons"
include("my-library-a")
include("my-library-b")

pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("my-plugins")
}
```

When I open it in IntelliJ, the root project gets a lot of of common tasks such as `test`, `build`, `publish` and so on, which, when called, get executed on every subproject.

Now, I decided to create a composite build with `my-commons` as one of the included builds to make better use of Gradle's `includeBuild` feature and the way it short-circuits the dependencies. My new structure looks like this:

```
my-project
├─my-commons
│ ├─my-library-a
│ │ ├─...
│ │ └─build.gradle.kts
│ ├─my-library-b
│ │ ├─...
│ │ └─build.gradle.kts
│ ├─my-plugins
│ │ ├─...
│ │ └─build.gradle.kts
│ └─settings.gradle.kts
├─my-project-x
│ ├─...
│ └─build.gradle.kts
├─my-project-y
│ ├─...
│ └─build.gradle.kts
└─settings.gradle.kts
```

The new root `settings.gradle.kts` looke like this (the one in `my-commons` is unchanged):

```kotlin
rootProject.name = "my-project"
includeBuild("my-commons")
includeBuild("my-project-x")
includeBuild("my-project-y")
```

However, when I open this project in IntelliJ, all the common tasks in the root project are gone. Even if I open up the task menu in `my-commons` included build, the tasks are gone from there as well. If I want to build or publish something, I need to do it manually for every single module.

At the same time, I have `my-commons` opened in a separate IntelliJ window, and all tasks are there intact.

My question is: how does Gradle decide whether to put these tasks into parent projects and how can I achieve the same effect in my composed build, given my project structure?